# Storing addresses and route information in a class data strucutre

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, structure, routes

Thanks in advance for your thoughts. I a very new programmer trying to create a way to store route and stops information in some sort of structure in C++. I first created a new class, called DeliveryVan. My initial thought was create class members, like DeliveryVan1.Stop1 etc, but then realized that each DeliveryVans' number of stops vary, and the amount of route information could also change between each DeliveryVan. To get all potential stops, I would have to create more stops than the largest number possible. I recently learned that that is a memory hog, and in the case of route information, that would be a very long list indeed. My first attempt was creating DeliveryVan.GPSLat1 through DeliveryVan.GPSLat1000, but I think that's pretty ugly solution.

I think a dynamic array would work, but am a little lost on how to create one when it is in a class structure.

So, after all that, it boils down to two questions: 1. How do you create a dynamic array within a class structure, and 2. How have other people stored route and stopping point data in a program that has multiple "DeliveryVans". Again, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `std::vector`, not any kind of "dynamic array" thing. Google it, read some about it and use it. If something doesn't work and you cannot figure it, post a question here and explain what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your class declaration:

```
std::vector<stop> stops;
```

where stop is a class/structure containing the definition of a stop. stops is a dynamic array that will manage its own size.